# How to join two array conditionally based on the date in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge

I have two arrays of users which have the same iDs. I want to merge them based on the updatedAt property that each user has. The user who has newer updatedAt property has priority.

```js
const users1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'user1', childUsers: [2], updatedAt: '2022-02-23T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 2, name: 'user2', childUsers: [3, 4], updatedAt: '2022-01-26T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 3, name: 'user3', childUsers: [2, 3], updatedAt: '2022-02-24T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 4, name: 'user4', childUsers: [2, 4], updatedAt: '2022-02-26T00:00:00.000Z' },
  ]
```

```js
const users2 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'user1', childUsers: [2], updatedAt: '2022-02-26T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 2, name: 'user2.1', childUsers: [3, 4], updatedAt: '2022-02-27T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 3, name: 'user3', childUsers: [2, 3], updatedAt: '2022-02-26T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 4, name: 'user4.1', childUsers: [2, 4], updatedAt: '2022-02-27T00:00:00.000Z' },
  ]
```

Output should be

```
const mergedUsers = [
{ id: 1, name: 'user1', childUsers: [2], updatedAt: '2022-02-26T00:00:00.000Z' },
{ id: 2, name: 'user2.1', childUsers: [3, 4], updatedAt: '2022-02-27T00:00:00.000Z' },
{ id: 3, name: 'user3', childUsers: [2, 3], updatedAt: '2022-02-26T00:00:00.000Z' },
{ id: 4, name: 'user4.1', childUsers: [2, 4], updatedAt: '2022-02-27T00:00:00.000Z' },
```

]

Comment: you missed the part where your attempt and expected output goes

Comment: Consider using an array for `users` and `users1` instead of an object?

Comment: Actually we can consider the users as array. I can then restructure them again to objects

Comment: @CelalettinTurgut may you share how you do that? Objects/arrays are not 1:1

Comment: I have edited the post. Now we have two array with users. At the end I should have an merged array with newer updatedAt property.

Comment: Still lacks the expected result.

Comment: great, not the part where you've tried something and are struggling with it - because stackoverflow isn't your coding service - though, someone will probably answer you

Comment: What is the difference between `mergedUsers` and `users2` ?

Comment: mergedUsers and users2 are accidentally the same. Because each user in users2 newer date then users1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group users by id, replacing any entry with a newer `updatedAt` property.

Once we have the grouped users, we can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get the desired result:

```js
const users1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'user1', childUsers: [2], updatedAt: '2022-02-23T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 2, name: 'user2', childUsers: [3, 4], updatedAt: '2022-01-26T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 3, name: 'user3', childUsers: [2, 3], updatedAt: '2022-02-24T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 4, name: 'user4', childUsers: [2, 4], updatedAt: '2022-02-26T00:00:00.000Z' },
  ]

const users2 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'user1', childUsers: [2], updatedAt: '2022-02-26T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 2, name: 'user2.1', childUsers: [3, 4], updatedAt: '2022-02-27T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 3, name: 'user3', childUsers: [2, 3], updatedAt: '2022-02-26T00:00:00.000Z' },
    { id: 4, name: 'user4.1', childUsers: [2, 4], updatedAt: '2022-02-27T00:00:00.000Z' },
  ]

const result = Object.values([...users1, ...users2].reduce((acc, user) => { 
    // Entry either does not exist or has an older updatedAt property
    if (!acc[user.id] || (user.updatedAt > acc[user.id].updatedAt)) {
        acc[user.id] = user;
    }
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Result:', result)
```

Comment: is the users1 not overwritten in [...users1, ...users2] ?

Comment: The arrays are concatenated, so we will keep the information from users1. The updatedAt property will determine which users are in the output.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok. It is not object destructuring.

Answer (score 1):

You want to compare each user in the first array with its similar one from the second array and choose the one with the higher updatedAt date.

```js
const users1 = [...];
const users2 = [...];

const merged = users1.map((user1) => {
  // loop through the users1 array 
  const duplicateUser = users2.find((user2) => user1.id === user2.id);
  // if a similar user was found
  if (duplicateUser) {
    // compare and return the user with the newer updatedAt date
    return new Date(duplicateUser.updatedAt) > new Date(user1.updatedAt)
      ? duplicateUser
      : user1;
  }
  return user1; // in the case of no duplicates 
});

console.log(merged);
```